# how to click an icon in table row and redirect to a new "details page" in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

I have a table with multiple columns and  rows, i want to click on icon in table row and be redirected to a new view with the details of that person, i have tried different ways but i am getting no luck. "Public function get data" is my function i am working on. here is my code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Transport View</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>


 <div id="banner" style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;">

    <img src="http://intranet.gfhs.local/stlc_trans/STLC-Tree-Logo-PACE.png">

 </div>

 <br> <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Search</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
</form>


<div ng-controller="decontroller">
<br><table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>

<tr><td></td><td></td><th style="text-align:center;" colspan="5"><h4>Attendance</h4></th><td></td><th style="text-align:center;" colspan="7"><h4>PCS Hours</h4></th></tr>    
<tr>

<td ng-click="sort('ParticipantName')"><b>Participant Name</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='ParticipantName'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('Function')"><b>Function</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Function'" ng-class="
{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
</td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_mo')"><b>Mon</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_mo'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
</td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_tu')"><b>Tue</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_tu'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_we')"><b>Wed</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_we'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_th')"><b>Thu</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_th'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_fr')"><b>Fr</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_fr'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>


<td ng-click="sort('Lanyard_Status')"><b>Lanyard Status</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Lanyard_Status'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>


<td ng-click="sort('PCS Monday Hours')"><b>PCS Mon</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Monday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Tuesday Hours')"><b>PCS Tue</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Tuesday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Wednesday Hours')"><b>PCS Wed</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Wednesday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Thursday Hours')"><b>PCS Thu</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Thursday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span> </td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Friday Hours')"><b>PCS Fr</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Friday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Saturday Hours')"><b>PCS Sat</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Saturday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Sunday Hours')"><b>PCS Sun</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Sunday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>


</tr> 


<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="n in list_data| orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:search track  by $index">

    <td>{{n.ParticipantName}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Function}}<a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_mo==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_tu==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_we==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_th==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_fr==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Lanyard_Status}}</td>
    <!--<td>{{n.AssistiveDevices}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Lanyard}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Wheelchair_Van}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.VanComments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Pick_Up_Time}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Drop_Off_Time}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.TransportationComments}}</td>-->
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Monday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Tuesday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Wednesday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Thursday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Friday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Saturday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Sunday}}</td>
    <!--<td>{{n.stlcid}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.physical_address}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.disenrolled}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.deceased}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Wheelchair_Van_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van_240_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van_360}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van_360_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Subaru_Impreza}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Subaru_Impreza_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.address_lat}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.address_long}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.phone}}</td>--> 

    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<dir-pagination-controls
   max-size="5"
   direction-links="true"
   boundary-links="true" >
</dir-pagination-controls>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('decontroller', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.list_data=[];
    $http.get("<?php echo site_url("index.php/transport/ajax_load_data")?>").success(function(result){
        console.log("GOT DATA: "+JSON.stringify(result));
        $scope.list_data=result;
    });



    $scope.sort = function(keyname){
    $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
}



});




</script>

<form action="<?php echo site_url("index.php/transport/get_data")?>"   method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="id"><br>
    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true">  </span>
</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Transport extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/      
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function list_show_data()
{

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('transport_view');

}

public function get_data()
{
    $show = $_POST['id'];

    trigger_error("ID FOUND IS $show");

}

public function details()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('details');
}

public function ajax_load_data()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $res = $this->db->get('transportation_properties')->result();
    $data_arr = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($res as $r)
    {
        $data_arr[$i]['id'] = $r->id;
        $data_arr[$i]['ParticipantName'] = $r->ParticipantName;
        $data_arr[$i]['Function'] = $r->Function;
        $data_arr[$i]['attendance_mo'] = $r->attendance_mo;
        $data_arr[$i]['attendance_tu'] = $r->attendance_tu;
        $data_arr[$i]['attendance_we'] = $r->attendance_we;
        $data_arr[$i]['attendance_th'] = $r->attendance_th;
        $data_arr[$i]['attendance_fr'] = $r->attendance_fr;
        $data_arr[$i]['Lanyard_Status'] = $r->Lanyard_Status;
        $data_arr[$i]['AssistiveDevices'] = $r->AssistiveDevices;
        $data_arr[$i]['Lanyard'] = $r->Lanyard;
        $data_arr[$i]['Wheelchair_Van'] = $r->Wheelchair_Van;
        $data_arr[$i]['Transit_Van'] = $r->Transit_Van;
        $data_arr[$i]['VanComments:'] = $r->VanComments;
        $data_arr[$i]['Pick_Up_Time'] = $r->Pick_Up_Time;
        $data_arr[$i]['Drop_Off_Time'] = $r->Drop_Off_Time;
        $data_arr[$i]['TransportationComments'] = $r->TransportationComments;
        $data_arr[$i]['PCS_Hours_Monday'] = $r->PCS_Hours_Monday;
        $data_arr[$i]['PCS_Hours_Tuesday'] = $r->PCS_Hours_Tuesday;
        $data_arr[$i]['PCS_Hours_Wednesday'] = $r->PCS_Hours_Wednesday;
        $data_arr[$i]['PCS_Hours_Thursday'] = $r->PCS_Hours_Thursday;
        $data_arr[$i]['PCS_Hours_Friday'] = $r->PCS_Hours_Friday;
        $data_arr[$i]['stlcid'] = $r->stlcid;
        $data_arr[$i]['physical_address'] = $r->physical_address;
        $data_arr[$i]['disenrolled'] = $r->disenrolled;
        $data_arr[$i]['deceased'] = $r->deceased;
        $data_arr[$i]['comments'] = $r->comments;
        $data_arr[$i]['Wheelchair_Van_comments'] = $r->Wheelchair_Van_comments;
        $data_arr[$i]['Transit_Van_240_comments'] = $r->Transit_Van_240_comments;
        $data_arr[$i]['Transit_Van_360'] = $r->Transit_Van_360;
        $data_arr[$i]['Transit_Van_360_comments'] = $r->Transit_Van_360_comments;
        $data_arr[$i]['Subaru_Impreza'] = $r->Subaru_Impreza;
        $data_arr[$i]['Subaru_Impreza_comments'] = $r->Subaru_Impreza_comments;
        $data_arr[$i]['address_lat'] = $r->address_lat;
        $data_arr[$i]['address_long'] = $r->address_long;
        $data_arr[$i]['phone'] = $r->phone;
        $i++;
    }

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    echo json_encode($data_arr);
}
```

}

Comment: When you say 'click on icon and redirect to...' are you referring to creating a link to another page, or using ajax to inject some data into the page?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am saying I have an icon on each row and when I click on it I would like to have another page open up populated with the persons details.

Comment: Well I answered some of your problems below, although I doubt that is the end of your problems. You might want to check your <tr /> as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have other problems, but this will not work.

```
site_url("index.php/transport/ajax_load_data")
```

Site url needs just the controller and the method (or assumes default method set in config and is default value of 'index')

```
site_url("transport/ajax_load_data")
```

From the docs:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url

You may also want to have a re-read of generating query results too as your creation of a multi dimensional array seems a bit long winded and possibly pointless too. You could just use result_array().

Docs again: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

However, you may well have your reasons for creating your result array in the way you do, but it seems at a quick glance to be a little inefficient.

---

Following a response:

To create a link in CI use:

```
  <a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/method'); ?>"><img glyph or text or whatever /></a>
```

Easy peasy. You have used placeholders like:

```
<td>{some_named_item}</td>
```

So you will have to locate where the placeholders are set and change those. Setting a link is very easy, is there some other issue that I have misunderstood?